# Coverting a string of tags to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string of tags that are usually separated by a single space, but the spacing may be inconsistent due to user input, hence the multiple spaces I added.

```
$somestring = "<h1> <a>   <h5> <img> <a> <strong>";
```

I'd like to store the tags into an array instead for easier manipulation. How can this be done with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [preg_split](http://www.php.net/preg_split):

```
$array = preg_split("/\s+/", $somestring);
```